# storing lambda functions in a list

Tags: python, lambda, list-comprehension

I'm trying to do the following thing:
I have a list:

```
classes = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

I have another list:

```
labels = [1,1,1,5,3]
```

I would like to create a list which contains 10 lists within it, so that list number i contains indicators whether the elements in the labels list are equal to class i.
For this example:

```
[[0,0,0,0,0],
 [1,1,1,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,1],
 [0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,1,0]
 [0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0]]
```

I tried the following code:

```
mappers = [np.vectorize(lambda x : 1 if x==c else 0) for c in classes]
indicators = [mapper(labels) for mapper in mappers]
```

However, I don't get what I want and I would like your help in this one. I get:

```
[[0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0]]
```

Comment: A common pitfall in Python: late binding. Use `mappers = [np.vectorize(lambda x, c=c: 1 if x==c else 0) for c in classes]` instead.

Comment: The problem is that you are capturing a reference to c, and that reference will always point to the last value of classes

Comment: Thanks! I highly appreciate your help.